# Code takes 1 min to process

Tags: android

This code goes through all pixels of picture alters the rgb of each one. When I run the code, it takes around 1-2 mins to complete. I think this is due to the loop completing 5.9 million times for the whole picture. How would I make this process much faster like > 10 seconds or close to this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
int r,g,b,colour;   
int [] allpixels = new int [picture.getHeight() * picture.getWidth()];
picture.getPixels(allpixels, 0, picture.getWidth(), 0, 0, picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight());

                    for(int i = 0; i < allpixels.length; i++)
                    {
                        colour = allpixels[i];
                        r = Color.red(colour);
                        b = Color.blue(colour);
                        g = Color.green(colour);

                        if(r < FIRSTSECTION){
                            r = FIRST;
                        }else if(r >= SECONDSECTION && r < THIRDSECTION){
                            r = SECOND;
                        }else if(r >= THIRDSECTION && r < FOURTHSECTION){
                            r = THIRD;
                        }else if(r >= FOURTHSECTION && r < FIFTHSECTION){
                            r = FORTH;
                        }

                        if(b < FIRSTSECTION){
                            b = FIRST;
                        }else if(b >= SECONDSECTION && b < THIRDSECTION){
                            b = SECOND;
                        }else if(b >= THIRDSECTION && b < FOURTHSECTION){
                            b = THIRD;
                        }else if(b >= FOURTHSECTION && b < FIFTHSECTION){
                            b = FORTH;
                        }

                        if(g < FIRSTSECTION){
                            g = FIRST;
                        }else if(g >= SECONDSECTION && g < THIRDSECTION){
                            g = SECOND;
                        }else if(g >= THIRDSECTION && g < FOURTHSECTION){
                            g = THIRD;
                        }else if(g >= FOURTHSECTION && g < FIFTHSECTION){
                            g = FORTH;
                        }

                        allpixels[i] = Color.argb(1, r, g, b);

                    }

                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    bitmap.setPixels(allpixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
                    drawableBitmap = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into using opengl to do something like this. This can be accomplished with a basic shader and will run much faster than doing it in Java. See this link for getting started with opengl es. https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html

This is also a pretty thorough tutorial although might be slightly dated http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/